# Why does $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L \|x-y \|$ imply $\| \nabla^2 f(x) \| \leq L$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

Let $f$ a twice continuously differentiable function. Also let $\nabla f$ be Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $L$, i.e.,

$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \leq L \|x-y \|.\tag{1}$$

On page 25 of Nesterov's [Lectures on Convex Optimization](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Lectures_on_Convex_Optimization.html?id=IPh6DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), it is stated that for any $s \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $a >0$, we have

$$\left\|s^T\left( \int_0^a \nabla^2 f (x + t s)dt \right) \right\| = \|\nabla f(x +a s) -\nabla f(x) \| \leq a L \| s \|\tag{2}$$

which when divided by $a$ and $a \to 0$ we obtain

$$\| \nabla^2 f(x) \| \leq L.\tag{3}$$

Thanks to @Oliver Díaz`'s comment, to prove $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$, we define $\phi(t)=\nabla f(x+ts)$. Then using $\frac{\partial \phi(t)}{\partial t} = s^T \nabla^2 f(x+ts)$ we have

$$\|\nabla f(x +a s) -\nabla f(x) \| = \|\phi(a) - \phi (0)\| = \left\|\int_0^a \frac{\partial \phi(t)}{\partial t} dt \right\| = \left\|\int_0^a s^T \nabla^2 f(x+ts) dt\right\|,$$ which by applying $(1)$ we get

$$\|\nabla f(x +a s) -\nabla f(x) \| \leq a L \| s\|.$$ Combining the latter two results we get $(2)$. Then, dividing by $a$, as the author in the book suggests, we get

$$\frac{1}{a}\left\|s^T\left( \int_0^a \nabla^2 f (x + t s)dt \right) \right\| = \frac{1}{a}\|\nabla f(x +a s) -\nabla f(x) \| \leq L \| s \|\tag{4}.$$ Could you please someone explain how we get $\|\nabla^2 f(x)\| \leq L $ by computing the limit of $(4)$ as $a\to 0$.

Comment: The function $\phi(t)=\nabla f(x+ts)$ ($x$ and $s$ fixed, is differentiable. Then the first identity follows from the fundamental theorem of Calculus (for Bochner integrals if your space is a Banach space, or the usual fundamental theorem of calculus if your space is finite dimensional). The rest again follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus: $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\int^{p+h}_pg(x)\,dx=g(x)$ at every point of continuity of $g$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I did some changes in my post any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, $\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \approx \nabla^2 f(x) (y - x)$, and the approximation is good when $y$ is close to $x$. So, $\| \nabla^2 f(x) (y-x) \| \approx \| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \| \leq L \| y - x \|$. This suggests that $\| \nabla^2 f(x) \| \leq L$.

Comment: @littleO I see you point but in order to get $\| \nabla^2 f(x) (y-x) \| \approx \| \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \| \leq L \| y - x \|$ we use $\| \nabla^2 f(x) \| \leq L$ and subsequently we do not clearly show $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$. Am I wrong?  Can we prove $\| \nabla^2 f(x) \| \leq L$ analytically  using $(4)$? Possibly the author of the book has done it some how.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{a} \left\|s^\top \int_0^a \nabla^2 f(x+ts) \, dt \right\|
\\
&= \frac{1}{a} \left\|s^\top \int_0^a (\nabla^2 f(x+ts) - \nabla^2 f(x) + \nabla^2 f(x)) \, dt \right\|
\\
&\ge \|s^\top \nabla^2 f(x)\| - \frac{1}{a} \left\|s^\top \int_0^a (\nabla^2 f(x+ts) - \nabla^2 f(x)) \, dt \right\|.
\end{align}

Since $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, the second term can be made smaller than any given $\epsilon > 0$ by choosing $a$ close enough to zero.

Thus we have
$$\|s^\top \nabla^2 f(x)\| - \epsilon \le L \|s\|$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$.

---

Details about the vanishing term:

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}
\left\|s^\top \int_0^a (\nabla^2 f(x+ts) - \nabla^2 f(x)) \, dt \right\|
\le \frac{1}{a} \int_0^a \|s^\top (\nabla^2 f(x+ts) - \nabla^2 f(x))\| \, dt.
\end{align}
Continuity of the second derivative of $f$ should imply that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $a$ such that
$\|s^\top (\nabla^2 f(x+ts) - \nabla^2 f(x))\| < \epsilon$
for any $s \in [0,a]$. Then the right-hand side can be bounded by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In  the inequality don't we need an absolute values? That is, $|\| x\| -\|y\| | \leq \|x-y \|$. Also, it is not clear to me why the second term can be made smaller than any $\epsilon>0$ by choosing $a\to 0$. Is ti possible to provide more details?

Comment: @darkmoor Well, $\|x-y\| \ge |\|x\|-\|y\|| \ge \|x\| - \|y\|$.

Comment: @darkmoor Added some details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I am trying to understand your argument about the continuity of second derivative of f and the implications of it but without success. Can you provide a more analytical explanation? Moreover, your final result is $\|s^\top \nabla^2 f(x)\| - \epsilon \le L \|s\|$. Also, How $\|s^\top \nabla^2 f(x)\| - \epsilon \le L \|s\|$ implies $\|\nabla^2 f(x)\| \leq L$?Thanks again.